# Angular Main Layout child component route cannot much

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

stupid problem, but I'm not clicking on it. I have main layout with nav bar and later side bar. I walso want to render 3 components: Products, Cart, Order.

I made child routes in the app.routing.modules.ts like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainlayoutComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    children: [
      { path: 'product', component: ProductsComponent  },
      { path: 'cart', component: CartComponent },
      { path: 'order', component: OrderComponent },
  ],
  },
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

However I get an error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'products'

Its been long time since angular, so I guess I'm missing something, but can't click what exactly. Wrong setup of child component?

Git url: https://github.com/TyroniUA/ang

Comment: so your route is "/product" but you are entering "/products" in your url

Comment: Ok, this one maybe an issue, but same goes with cart and order. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when you chage the `pathMatch = 'full'` to `pathMatch = 'prefix'`

**Explanation:**

'full' results in a route hit when the remaining, unmatched segments of the URL match is the prefix path

'prefix' tells the router to match the redirect route when the remaining URL begins with the redirect route's prefix path.

Comment: Jesus, forgot about "prefix" stuff. Thank you kindly sir))

Comment: Ah no, I was too fast. It doesn't work correctly. It worked because I tested also in App Component, but when remove from it and only MainLayout component left - ir doesn't work

Comment: @VolodymyrRudov-Tsymbalist do you have a `router-outlet` inside `MainLayoutComponent`?